# I want to install pysockect or any other websocket in centOs 64 bits

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, socket

I have get a tutorial to install pywebsocket in linux.

http://www.travisglines.com/web-coding/how-to-set-up-apache-to-serve-html5-websocket-applications-with-pywebsocket

But I am using centOs for my apache server. I want something by which I can install websocket and use it in my php. I have centOs 64 bit.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Can't find anything distributin-specifc in that tutorial expect the mod_python setup. You only have to use "yum" to install mod_python instead of apt-get using this command:

```
yum install mod_python
```